# Embedding Instagram post using editor js in react-native

Tags: react-native, instagram, embed, editorjs

I'm trying to embed an instagram post using editor js on react-native. I'm unable to find any approaches similar to,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/editorjs-youtube-embed

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what about https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-instagram-embed this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

[Editor JS Links](https://github.com/editor-js/embed#list-of-services-supported)

Simply add as follows under tools:

```
embed: {
        class: Embed,
        config: {
          services: {
            instagram: true,
          },
        },
      },
```